# How i can change password of a user with custom method using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using rails 3 with gem devise.Devise has built in method for change password.But i want

that admin can reset password of any user and how i can do it please help..

Comment: You can always do it as a simple update_attributes, and don't forget to notify the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom method and also define routes for it

```
 <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => '/administrator', :action =>                  'change_password',:id => @user.id}, :html => {:id => 'admin_update_form',:method => :put}) do |f| %>

<div class="change-pass">
  <h2>Change Passwords</h2>

  <div class="pass-detail">
    <div class="username-btn">
      <label>Passwords</label>
      <%= f.password_field :password, :class=> 'fields' %>
    </div>
    <div class="username-btn" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
      <label>Confirm Passwords</label>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class=> 'fields' %>
    </div>
    <%=hidden_field_tag 'user_ids',:id => 'user_ids'  %>
    <div class="username-btn_button">
      <%= f.submit 'change password', :id => 'password_btn' ,:class => 'reg-findjob'%>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In controller code

```
def change_password
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   if @user.update_attributes(:password => params[:user][:password],    :password_confirmation => params[:user][:password_confirmation])
     flash[:notice] = 'Password was changed successfully.'
     render :text => 'ok'
   else
    flash[:error]=[]
    @user.errors.full_messages.each do |error|
      flash[:error] << error
    end       
end
```

In controller find user and update its password attribute.I am sending user id with form

whose password is to changed or you can do it according your requirement.